# How can I go about making temporary test connections in pcb while prototyping without soldering?

Tags: prototyping, testing, tools, development-tools

I recently ordered some PCB bits from Adafruit to assemble a widget. I want to make temporary connections between different PCBs, but am not convinced I want to solder and then desolder and resolder wires while I am testing and prototyping.

My initial thought was that there might be some sort of cone-like connector I could shove through the pads that would make temporary contact, but can't seem to find anything.

Is there a solution to this problem? I could use the headers that came with the PCBs but then I'd have to desolder those or buy new PCBs once I had the wiring diagram figured out, which is something I'm also not keen on doing.

Comment: Um why don't you use the appropriate connectors that mate with the headers?

Comment: Or you can solder the headers and use wire wrap wire.  If you want something truly temporary you can come up with some jig for pogo pins, usually press style but occasionally more a clothespin clamp, however this is usually only worth the effort if you are going to be doing many of the same thing.

Comment: Duplicate of https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/249140/how-can-i-make-connection-on-pcb-circuit-board-holes-without-solder-for-proto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to answer the questions which aren't already covered in the old question kindly mentioned by *Transistor*:

[How can I make connection on pcb (circuit board) holes without solder (for prototyping)?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/249140/how-can-i-make-connection-on-pcb-circuit-board-holes-without-solder-for-proto)

> I could use the headers that came with the PCBs but then I'd have to desolder those or buy new PCBs once I had the wiring diagram figured out, which is something I'm also not keen on doing.

You don't *have to* desolder the headers from the small module later. One approach is to solder standard headers (male or female - your choice, there are benefits to each) into the small modules you buy from Adafruit (or wherever).

While prototyping, you can use "Dupont cables" to make connections to other PCBs, or you might plug the small module (with its headers) directly into a breadboard.

When you have decided on the final design, you fit equivalent **opposite-gender** headers onto your final PCB / perfboard or whatever. Then plug the small module with its headers, onto those opposite-gender headers which you have soldered onto your final board.

When you are planning this, think about which gender of headers are most suitable for you on each side (module and final board), and which way "up" you want the small module to be, when fitted to the final board.

This is similar the approach used for TI BoosterPacks, Arduino Shields etc. where you "stack" boards using opposite-gender 0.1" pitch headers.

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way to access such signals other than by making them available to such connectors. This concept is also used in test jigs, in which instead of connectors such signals are available on pads for a bed of nails board tester.